# How to Transfer Edited theme on Local Host to Azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure, xampp, wordpress-theming

I have to transfer my Local host edited WordPress theme to Azure WordPress.

I have edited a WordPress theme on my Local Xampp Server. After that, I got to know that to transfer my theme, I need to install a WordPress plug-in called Duplicator. I have installed and downloaded the generated files. Now, I want to transfer that theme to my newly made Azure Account WordPress
but I'm unable to do so and there is no descriptive video or post that I can find.

I can not find Azure WordPress root directory.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Move Your WordPress Site to Microsoft Azure: Step by Step Guide**

**Backup your WordPress Site with cPanel**

- Choose the “Full Backup” option which will include all your files and databases

**Backup your WordPress Site with a Plugin**

- Install and activate the plugin and you will see a new menu item under “Tools” named “Backups”,click the “Settings” link and choose the “Database and Files” option.

**Export Your Site Content**

- “Tools” > “Export” and choose “All Content” and download the Export file.
  Move WordPress Content to Azure

Now you have your site backup, the content you will need to set the site up on Azure is as follows :

- The /wp-content folder – This contains any uploaded images and files, your plugins and your themes
- The Export file – This contains all your blog posts, comments, pages and any other content.

**Upload Content Via FTP**

- Login to Azure portal and choose your website from the “Websites” link on the left-hand side, click your site name and the “Dashboard” and you will see a link on the bottom right named “Setup Deployment Credentials”

  Enter a username and password in the popup box and these will be your FTP login credentials

**Import Content- Download and import file attachment**

- To import your content, in the new Azure installation visit “Tools” > “Import” and select the WordPress importer from the list

**Setting the Permalinks**

- “Settings” > “Permalinks” and choose your option there. For instance, choose “Post Name” and WordPress will create a “web.config” file for you ( on PHP hosting, the file is .htaccess )

You can follow this steps.

You can get the more details by

- https://wplift.com/move-wordpress-microsoft-azure
- https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2016/10/migrate-wordpress-site-azure-inapp-mysql/